# Question marks and quotations

Tags: quotation-marks, question-marks

According to GrammarBook.com, "the placement of question marks with quotation marks follows logic. If a question is within the quoted material, a question mark should be placed inside the quotation marks."

She asked, "Will you still be my friend?" is correct. However, do we need a period after closing the quotation?

"Will you still be my friend?"**.** No, I will not.

or

"Will you still be my friend?" No, I will not.

Do you agree with the saying, "All's fair in love and war"? I know we don't need a period for this sentence because the question mark needs to be on the outside, but I'm not sure about the previous example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your examples serve to answer your own question.

If no full stop (period) is required after the question in quotes:

> "Will you still be my friend?"

It will not be required either by the addition of a subsequent sentence.

That's to say that the response **No, I will not.** does not influence the punctuation of the previous question. It's a separate sentence.

A writer would probably start a new paragraph with the response.

https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/full-stops-after-question-marks-if-outside-a-quote.1776224/
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/explore/is-a-question-mark-a-full-stop/
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/punctuation/punctuation-in-direct-speech